# How to join multiple many to many tables

Tags: postgresql, query, relations

I have tables - games, game_views, game_views_game_links, genres, games_genres_links.

I need to count views from game_views, filter by them and join genres table to genres field.

If i use only 2 joins with game_views, game_views_game_links i give normal result.

My query is give all genres 1 view, can i separate this?

**Relations:**

- games many to many genres
- games one to many game_views

this query gives correct result

```
SELECT "games"."id" AS "id",
    COUNT("game_views"."id") AS "views",
    "games"."created_at",
    "games"."updated_at"
FROM "games"

LEFT JOIN "game_views_game_links" AS "gvgl" ON "games"."id" = "gvgl"."game_id"
LEFT JOIN "game_views" ON "game_views"."id" = "gvgl"."game_view_id"

WHERE "game_views"."created_at" > '2023-03-13T12:00:02+03:00'
GROUP BY "games"."id"
ORDER BY "views" DESC,
    "updated_at" ASC
```

this query doubled

```
SELECT "games"."id" AS "id",
    COUNT("game_views"."id") AS "views",
    "games"."created_at",
    "games"."updated_at"
FROM "games"

LEFT JOIN "game_views_game_links" AS "gvgl" ON "games"."id" = "gvgl"."game_id"
LEFT JOIN "game_views" ON "game_views"."id" = "gvgl"."game_view_id"

LEFT JOIN "games_genres_links" AS "ggl" ON "games"."id" = "ggl"."game_id"
LEFT JOIN "genres" ON "genres"."id" = "ggl"."genre_id"

WHERE "game_views"."created_at" > '2023-03-13T12:00:02+03:00'
GROUP BY "games"."id"
ORDER BY "views" DESC,
    "updated_at" ASC
```

Comment: WHat about `count(DISTINCT ...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate before joining. Note the use of `JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN` for the views, because your filter is effectively doing that anyway.

```sql
SELECT
  g.id,
  gvgl.views,
  gg.genres,
  g.created_at,
  g.updated_at
FROM games AS g
JOIN (
    SELECT
      gvgl.game_id,
      COUNT(*) AS views
    FROM game_views_game_links AS gvgl
    JOIN game_views AS gv ON gv.id = gvgl.game_view_id
    WHERE gv.created_at > '2023-03-13T12:00:02+03:00'
    GROUP BY
      gvgl.game_id
) gvgl ON g.id = gvgl.game_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      ggl.game_id,
      array_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
          'id', gen.id,
          'name', g.name)
      ) AS genres
    FROM games_genres_links AS ggl
    JOIN genres g ON g.id = ggl.genre_id
) gg ON g.id = gg.game_id
ORDER BY
  gvgl.views DESC,
  g.updated_at ASC;
```

Comment: thx, it's work great

Answer (score 0):

split views to subquery

```
SELECT "games"."id" AS "id",
    (SELECT COUNT("game_views"."id")
        FROM "game_views"
        LEFT JOIN "game_views_game_links" ON "game_views"."id" = "game_views_game_links"."game_view_id"
        WHERE "game_views_game_links"."game_id" = "games"."id"
            AND "game_views"."created_at" > '2023-03-13T12:00:02+03:00') AS "views",
    "games"."name",
    "games"."steam",
    "games"."version",
    "games"."trailers",
    "games"."description",
    "games"."short_description",
    "games"."requirements",
    "games"."good_review",
    "games"."poor_review",
    "games"."created_at",
    "games"."updated_at",
    ARRAY_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id',
                                GENRES.ID,
                                'name',
                                GENRES.NAME)) AS GENRES
FROM "games"
LEFT JOIN "games_genres_links" AS "ggl" ON "games"."id" = "ggl"."game_id"
LEFT JOIN "genres" ON "genres"."id" = "ggl"."genre_id"
WHERE "games"."id" =
        (SELECT "gvgl"."game_id"
            FROM "game_views_game_links" AS "gvgl"
            WHERE "gvgl"."game_id" = "games"."id"
            GROUP BY "gvgl"."game_id")
GROUP BY "games"."id"
ORDER BY "views" DESC,
    "updated_at" ASC
```

Comment: No need for all those double quotes.

Comment: The subquery makes no sense, it has an `IN` and a correlated `=` and a `GROUP BY`. Stick to one option or the other: either an `EXISTS` or an `IN`

Comment: Also you are querying the views twice, you only need to do it once.